# In a conservative line integral, do flipping the points make the integral negative?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I know that conservative line integrals are path independent. But what do flipping the points change the value of the integral. For example any path from A to B in a certain domain will be the same, but will B to A just be the negative of it?

I know that for vector fields, it's generally turns negative and for scalar fields it's the same value regardless of the starting and ending points. But for conservative vector fields, is it any different?

---

Yeah I just realized I was stupid. You're going with the vector or against the vector so the 'work' or the value will be negative if you flip the points. Thanks for the comments people!

Comment: It might be helpful to consider what it is that the line integral physically represents.  Do you have any intuition about that?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Idk man, I'm learning all of this and I think it's negative since you're going against the field or with the field. So yeah just tell me I gotta learn Green's Theorem and Curl as well.

Answer (score 3):

For conservative fields, we have

$$\int_C  F \cdot \mathrm d \mathbf r = f(\mathbf r(b)) - f(\mathbf r(a))$$

which means that although the initial and final points are the only things that matter, switching the endpoints produces the opposite result.

Comment: Just realized it, thanks for the effort though. +1